# truffle can not build success

Tags: truffle-contract, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, truffle-compile

when I fllow this document step by step [enter link description here](http://www.techtonet.com/how-to-install-and-execute-truffle-on-an-ubuntu-16-04/),I have something wrong with my truffle build,and I delete truffle.js ,this is photo, please help thx!!

[image]

Comment: its better to follow https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-testing-frontend-app-truffle-3